# In how many ways can the group $\mathbb Z_5$ act on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, cyclic-groups

$\mathbb Z_{5}$ is the group to act on the set $\{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$. In how many ways is that possible?
Now $0$ will give the identity map. $1$ will give a  bijection in $5!$ ways so will the others and the number of possible bijections being $5!$ the bijections given by $1$ will coincide with those given by others. All get mixed up here.

Comment: Note that $1\in \Bbb Z_5$ has order $5$. That means that the action that $1$ does on the set needs to have order that divides $5$.

Comment: This sounds confusing. Are we mixing up the group operation with a group action?

Answer (score 20):

An equivalent way of thinking of group actions is as follows: a group $G$ acting on a (finite) set $X$ is exactly a homomorphism $$\theta:G\to S_{|X|}$$
where $S_{|X|}$ is the symmetric group on $|X|$ elements, and $\theta(g)$ is the permutation of $X$ given by $x\mapsto g(x)$. And every such homomorphism gives a group action: define $g(x)$ to be where $\theta(g)$ sends $x$.

> How many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\to S_5$?

$\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, so any homomorphism will be completely determined by where it sends the generator $1$. But $1$ has order $5$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$, so it can be sent only to elements with orders dividing $5$.

So we just need to find the number of elements of orders $1$ and $5$ in $S_5$. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 7):

In this answer, let $C_m$ denote the cyclic group of order $m$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  I also write $C_0$ for the infinite cyclic group.

There is one obvious group action: the trivial action.  Now, we consider a nontrivial action.  Then, there exists an element of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, say $1$, not fixed by $C_5$.  However, the size of the orbit of $1$ would then be $5$ (since the size of the orbit divides the order of $C_5$ and it is not $1$).  Hence, this action is transitive as the orbit must be the whole $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Therefore, this action is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ on a circle (where $1\in C_5$ is rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{5}$).  On the other hand, every permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ on a circle can be made an action of $C_5$ on this set.  There are $(5-1)!=24$ such permutations.  Hence, in total, there are $1+24=25$ possible actions of $C_5$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

In how many ways can the group $C_6$ act on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

> **Hint:** The answer is $1+15+40+45+120+15+40+120=396$.

In general, if $a^m_n$ is the number of ways the group $C_m$ can act on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, where $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,a^m_n\,\frac{t^n}{n!}=\exp\left(\sum_{\substack{{d\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\\{d\mid m}}}\,\frac{t^d}{d}\right)\,.$$  In particular, it can be shown that $a^0_n=n!$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, or
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,a^0_n\,\frac{t^n}{n!}=\exp\left(\sum_{\substack{{d\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\\{d\mid 0}}}\,\frac{t^d}{d}\right)=\exp\left(\sum_{d=1}^\infty\,\frac{t^d}{d}\right)=\exp\Bigg(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)\Bigg)=\frac{1}{1-t}\,.$$

Comment: What is $t$ in your answer ??

Comment: The variable $t$ is just a dummy variable.  Do you know anything about generating functions?

Comment: No, never heard about it.

Comment: It's time to do a google search on the topic of generating functions, then.  What I used is called an exponential generating function.  It's a nice counting technique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I don't understand how you calculated the no. of ways for $\mathbb Z_6$. Can you please elaborate ??

Comment: The set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ must be partitioned into orbits whose sizes are divisors of $6$, i.e., $1,2,3,6$.  Here are all $8$ possible choices of orbit sizes: $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$, $(1,1,1,1,2)$, $(1,1,1,3)$, $(1,1,2,2)$, $(1,2,3)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(3,3)$, and $(6)$.  You have to count how many group actions there are with given orbit sizes.  For example, $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ has only $1$ action, $(6)$ has $(6-1)!=120$ actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stabilizers must have order either $1$ or $5$, the orbits must have accordingly size either $5$ or $1$. Therefore, the only allowed orbit equations are $5=1+1+1+1+1$ and $5=5$. The former corresponds to the trivial action (the kernel is the whole $\Bbb Z_5$). The latter corresponds to a (transitive and) faithful action, being all the stabilizers trivial; so it is equivalent to an embedding of $\Bbb Z_5$ into $S_5$. Every (cyclic) subgroup of order $5$ of $S_5$, say $H_i,$ is an image of $\Bbb Z_5$ under such an embedding and, for each $H_i(\cong C_5)$, there are $4$ distinct isomorphisms $\varphi_{ij}\colon \Bbb Z_5\to H_i$, $j=1,2,3,4$ (recall that for a prime $p$, $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)\cong C_{p-1}$). So we are left with searching for how many $H_i$ are there; now, in general there are ${n!\over k(n-k)!}$ $k$-cycles in $S_n$, and hence $24=(5-1)!$ $5$-cycles in $S_5$; each of them lies in one and only one $H_i$, which in turn are pairwise with trivial intersection; therefore, there are six $H_i$and overall $6\cdot4=24$ nontrivial homomorphisms $\varphi\colon \Bbb Z_5\to S_5$ or, equivalently, as many nontrivial actions of $\Bbb Z_5$ on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.